# Where the event logs bind to?

Tags: solidity, ether

I have question regarding to how event log bind to an address
Let said:

- Contract A which handle logic
- Contract B is erc20 token contract

For the flow, Contract A call transfer token on Contract B

So my question is, the Transfer Log bind to Contract A or Contract B?
It seems like the Event Log bind to Contract A

Here is an example tx I found https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2c476dd9b96b2925f345d18d7b254762e9cd8a290ab79b8f38383da34cded6c3